# Programmatically take a screenshot from service

Tags: android, image, screenshot, capture, snapshot

it is easy to this code

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = MyView.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

and it works great , but this is the case if there is activity.

How can I take a screenshot from service ?

my goal to take a screenshot ones in a hour ,e.i to to take screen shut every hour for example in 12 then in 1 then in 2 .... and so on

Comment: screen shuts are very important!... please tell me if you find a solutions

Answer (score 7):

To capture ***ScreenShot*** for your activity you have to need a `View` of your activity, and which one is not present in your service so you have to make a TimerTask which will call your activity at every hour and your activity responding it to with current appear view and you can capture the `ScreenShot` from that. (I think this one is only solution for your problem.)

Or If you want to take a ScreenShot of your current device screen (any application) then you have to **root permission**, and read `framebuffer` for that which will give raw data of current screen then convert it to bitmap or any picture file you can do it in your service.

Comment: hi @user370305, can you please give me some example code for reading framebuffer... i need a urgent requirment...

Comment: @kalandar - Look at http://www.pocketmagic.net/2010/11/android-native-screen-capture-application-using-the-framebuffer/#.UTG82TfDs1o

Answer (score 3):

Android Screenshot Library (ASL) provides means for taking snapshots of phone's screen without the need for signing your application or having privileged (root) access to the Android system
[Click here for ASL](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/Usage)