# to get a current screen view from my own application

Tags: android

I am running one external application from my own application and when this application opens, i want to get a view of that external application in my own application. So that i can capture a screenshot of it. Please help me in this.

Comment: Why is there a downvote? Questions about things that may not be possible are still good questions.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think thats possible. The communication between applications or even activities is limited to passing data  to each other through intents. I don't think sharing references to objects across applications is possible. Please correct me.

Such a thing would be possible if they allowed you to launch an external application in your own window.

Answer (score 0):

I did some search and it is quite likely it may not be possible, however I have found a possible way. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481715/programmatically-take-a-screenshot-from-service) link, which states that

> Or If you want to take a ScreenShot of your current device screen (any
>   application) then you have to root permission, and read framebuffer
>   for that which will give raw data of current screen then convert it to
>   bitmap or any picture file you can do it in your service.

Which means that whenever your application starts an application you will need to create a service that reads the `framebiffer`, but if an activity is used for taking the screenshot then it will not be useful because the screenshot will then be of that activity.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293615/how-can-i-get-root-permissions-through-the-android-sdk) and [this](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/), these links are related to your question as well. And see if it works.

Hope this helps.